# How to create random points inside polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, random, point

Has anyone created random points within polygons in QGIS 3.0? I created multiple polygons and would like to create multiple random points within each polygon. I am trying to have the number of points within each polygon to be determined by the area of the polygon (I would like it to cover 20% of the polygon). In older versions of QGIS there is the option to select point density and to select the percentage of points with relation to the polygon. However in QGIS 3.0 there is no option to select the percentage of the polygon to cover with points. Is there a way to create these random points within polygons having them cover 20% of the polygon?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to do a bit of modeling, first.  How much area do you want each point to represent?  You could jam an infinite number of geometric points inside a polygon.  They have no area.  The object you are trying to model probably does have an area.  When you know that value, get the total area of the polygon, and calculate the number of objects it would take to cover 20% of that.  Then, space that many points randomly inside the polygon.

Comment: I am using the points as markers of where to place the features in the future. The points are being used as a reference. The objects that will be replacing the points, later in time, will have different sizes.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to know what area will be covered by the points if you don't yet know what size the points will represent.